# how to localise a date in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, java-time

I want to localise a date in Kotlin Android, so that when I change language I see date accordingly

Date coming through is : `Tue Feb 06 00:00:00 GMT 2024`
What I want to get is
Italian - `lun 5 feb`
German - `Mo. 5. Feb.`

Android system should do this

what I have got so far

```
private fun testFun(date: Date): String {
    val fullDateFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE d MMM")
    return date.toLocalDate(timeZoneId).format(fullDateFormatter)
}
    
fun Dates.toLocalDate(timeZoneId: ZoneId): LocalDate {
    return java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(time).atZone(timeZoneId).toLocalDate()
}
```

to `LocalDate` time is wrong as it returns me `Mar 5 Feb`

please suggest how I can achieve this

thanks
R

Comment: Have you tried to pass a `Locale` to your `DateTimeFormatter`? Maybe `Locale.ITALIAN` or `Locale.GERMAN`…

Comment: Oh, in case you receive a *date* and you actually want the day before that date, you should call `minusDays(1)` on the `LocalDate`. Could be a type and you don't want to. adjust the value, just switch its representation…